# How to install Dia plugins on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, python, plugins

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise). I already install and using Dia.
I need to use `dia_orgchart.py` downloaded from http://dia-installer.de.

As the instruction given, I try to put `dia_orgchart.py` to `~/.dia/python/` but seems I don't have such directory.

I have `~/.dia/` directory but there's no `python` directory inside.

I also try to put it on `/usr/share/dia/python` but I don't know how to load the plugin inside of the application.

How should I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python` directory does not exist by default in `~/.dia` you have to create it, open a Terminal and type:

```
cd ~/.dia
mkdir python
```

Then copy the `dia_orgchart.py` plugin (available [here](http://dia-installer.de/src/dia_orgchart.py)) to `~/.dia/python`.
Restart `dia` and load the [sample csv file](http://dia-installer.de/samples/orgchart_example.csv).

[image]

[Source](http://dia-installer.de/doc/organization_chart.html.en)